# How do you normalize the rows of a document term matrix in place in R?

Tags: r, tm, topicmodels

I have a DocumentTermMatrix named train_dtm and I want to normalize the frequency counts of the term frequencies in all the documents. The problem I am facing is that the resulting matrix should also be of type DocumentTermMatrix because I want to pass the normalized matrix to another method LDA of the TopicModels package in R.

Below is the method I am using:

```
docs_dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(docs)
```

Now, I want the rows of the above documenttermmatrix to be normalized. I even tried adding the control parameter via

```
docs_dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(docs, control=list(weighting = function(x) weightTf(x, normalize=TRUE)))
```

but the above call throws an error saying

```
Error in weightTf(x, normalize=TRUE): unused argument (normalize = TRUE)
```

I have written the method to normalize the values of train_dtm using apply() method but it does not return a matrix of type DocumentTermMatrix.

Is there another way to accomplish the above task?

Comment: Do you have a minimal working example?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have pasted my code above.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try passing the weighting argument directly, e.g.:

```
docs_dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(docs, control = list(weighting = weightTf, normalize = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Normalize after creating the dtm:

```
docs_dtm_norm <- t(apply(docs_dtm, 1, function(x) x/sqrt(sum(x^2))))
```